# Upper bound for decreasing sequence $a_{n+1}\leq a_{n} - C a_{n+1}^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

A monotonically decreasing sequence $(a_n)$ satisfy $a_{n+1}\leq a_{n} - C a_{n+1}^2$ where $C$ is a constant. If $a_1$ is known, could we verify that

$$a_n \leq \frac{3/(2C) + a_1}{n}$$

Comment: Can you figure out an upper bound for $a_2$?  Think about the quadratic formula and the shape of a parabola...

Comment: Why is the sequence decreasing?

Comment: @MichaelBurr Using quadratic formula can give a bound, but I saw there is a tighter bound for $a_n$. The author only mentioned it is easy to induct. I spent one day but still could not verify it.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Decreasing sequence is a condition I have forgot to add.

Answer (score 0):

The question has seriously changed since the original posting.  This answer addresses the original question.

Sketch: Suppose that you know $a_1$, now consider $a_2$.  In this case, we have that (after rearrangement)
$$
Ca_{2}^2+a_{2}-a_1\leq 0.
$$
Consider the associated inequality
$$
Cx^2+x-a_1\leq 0.
$$
If $C<0$, then $x$ can be arbitrarily large.  If $C=0$, then $x\leq a_1$.  Therefore, let's assume that $C>0$.  The behavior at $\infty$ for a quadratic whose coefficient of $x^2$ is positive is that the value grows to infinity, so the only places where the given inequality hold are between the roots of $Cx^2+x-a_1$.  The roots of this expression are
$$
\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-1+4Ca_1}}{2C}.
$$

Note that we must have $1+4Ca_1\geq 0$ for the square root to make sense, so I would start by considering the case where $a_1>0$ as any other case requires more subtle analysis.  Similarly, since we're interested in the the growth rate, I suggest choosing the positive solution:
$$
\frac{1\pm\sqrt{-1+4Ca_1}}{2C}.
$$
This hint used $a_1$, but you could certainly use $a_2$ to get $a_3$ in a similar manner.  Therefore, you're considering 
$$
a_{n+1}=\frac{-1+\sqrt{1+4Ca_n}}{2C}.
$$
One may be able to get the desired bound by considering the Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1+x}$ centered at $0$.  You might also try an induction using this recurrence to see if the given inequality holds.